# How to call the functions that are inside a python class

Tags: python

I have a python class where I have nested  functions. Im not able to call the functions that are nested.

```
class Data:
    __instance__ = None
    def writeCleanData(df,path,d_path,row,days,lk):
        Data.write(Data.unify(df,row),path,"append")
        d_path[path] = os.path.split(d_path[path])[0]
        Data.CreateFolder(d_path[path],lk)
        Data.CleanPath(lk,path,d_path)
        
        def unify(df, onCol):
            return df.repartition(10, onCol)
        
        def CreateFolder(base, lake):
            x = fd.path(base)
            
    def write(df,data_nm,mode):
        Data.get_instance._write(df,data_nm,mode)
```

Im getting `'Data' has no attribute 'unify'`

Please let me know how to call  these  functions

Comment: You _can't_ access those functions - they're not just inside the class, they're locally defined inside the method. Maybe they _shouldn't_ be?

Comment: I think technically, you can access those functions, but only from the `writeCleanData` method (which, due to the lack of `self`, is a static method. In fact, everything is defined and called as a static method, which is awkward to say the least). All in all, you'll want to review and learn how to use classes. Or, possibly better here, simply avoid classes, and use functions. In this case, if you remove the class part, and turn everything into standard functions, your code can function normally, since you're not using anything class-specific anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`Data` cannot access the `unify` function, just like it cannot access any other object declared inside the scope of the `writeCleanData` method. If you want to access it via the `Data` class, it should be defined as a method of the the said class. If you want to make it a class method rather than an object method, you can achieve it as follows:

```py
class Data:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def unify(df, onCol):
        return df.repartition(10, onCol)
```

`unify` and `CreateFolder` seem like utility functions, so they would be better off as static methods, although it makes little practical difference in this case. [This article](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) explains all of these concepts nicely.